# How do I select the skin with keyboard for Android Emulator from SDK tools revision 21

Tags: android-emulator

On Android SDK 20.0.3 I could get this
[image: On Android SDK 20.0.3 I could get this]

but now on Rev 21 I cannot get the skin with keyboard. How do I get the skin with keyboard on my emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I have check AVD Manager, I think you can not get emulator screen with keyboard but instead you can use your physical keyboard (the one attached with your PC or Laptop).

However you can have other buttons like HOME, MENU etc on screen.

[image]